# upgrade plugin in wordpress

Tags: plugins

I am using wordpress on my live server which only uses sftp using an ssh key.

I want to install and upgrade plugins, but it appears that you are required to enter your ftp login to install the plugins. Is there a way to install and upgrade plugins by manually uploading the files instead of having wordpress handle the entire process?

Comment: Note that in context of filesystem access when WP says "FTP" it usually means "SSH or FTP, whatever works".

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just download the plugin and unzip it overriding the existing plugin directory in `wp-content\plugins`, or in a new dir named as the plugin if you want to install a new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are being asked for the FTP credentials, check the [Upgrade constants](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants) that you can include in your `wp-config.php` to bypass that request.

To upgrade a plugin manually, it's a matter of uploading its folder to your server in the following path: `/wp-content/plugins/`.

And, in the manual process, uploading and/or deleting a folder can take some time. And, if the plugin is **active**, this could lead to a temporary break or malfunction of the site. So to make it transparent as possible, use the following technique.

1. Create an auxiliary folder `/wp-content/to-delete/`
2. Upload your updated plugin directly in `/wp-content/`
3. When finished, move the old plugin (`/wp-content/plugins/the-plugin/`) to the auxiliary folder
4. Immediately, move the updated plugin folder (`/wp-content/the-plugin/`) to the plugins folder
5. Delete the old plugin folder (`/wp-content/to-delete/the-plugin`)

All this assumes that you understand WordPress [file/folder structure](http://ditio.net/2011/07/26/wordpress-directory-structure-2/).

Comment: +1. While @stefano answers the literal question being asked, this answer gets to the heart of the underlying issue, and provides the proper work-around.